# under which layout banner ad should place?

Tags: android, layout, admob, banner

i am newbie and developing a quiz app. there is four button at the bottom. Everything is working fine, but when i place a banner ad at the bottom buttons are not working properly. i think, i am placing banner ad under wrong layout. please check my xml and suggest me the right place of banner ad. thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mainScrollView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context="com.myquiz.MainActivity">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/quizBody"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="#dc143c"
            android:background="@color/questionColor"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/question552"
            android:textAppearance="@style/appearanceBody" />
        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/group552"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/answer552"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/question552A" />
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/question552B" />
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/question552C" />
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/question552D" />
        </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/quizBody"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/result"
            android:onClick="getResults"
            android:text="@string/resultButtonText" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/showanswers"
            android:onClick="correctAnswers"
            android:text="@string/showAnswersButtonText" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/ResetTest"
            android:onClick="resetTest"
            android:text="@string/resetButtonText" />
</LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/model12expl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#87cefa"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/button"
        android:text="View Explanation" />
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your code inside the RelativeLayout

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="info.androidhive.admob.MainActivity">

       //Place your code here


<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/mainScrollView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context="com.myquiz.MainActivity">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/quizBody"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="#dc143c"
            android:background="@color/questionColor"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/question552"
            android:textAppearance="@style/appearanceBody" />
        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/group552"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/answer552"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/question552A" />
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/question552B" />
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/question552C" />
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/question552D" />
        </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/quizBody"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/result"
            android:onClick="getResults"
            android:text="@string/resultButtonText" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/showanswers"
            android:onClick="correctAnswers"
            android:text="@string/showAnswersButtonText" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/ResetTest"
            android:onClick="resetTest"
            android:text="@string/resetButtonText" />
</LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/model12expl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#87cefa"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/button"
        android:text="View Explanation" />
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
//end
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_home_footer">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Where in my XML.

Comment: place your xml codes above the  com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView

Comment: My XML is start with Scroll View

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example. Place your Scrollview inside Relative layout.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_id"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollLayout"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/adView">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/advancedLayouts_scroll_view_lorem_ipsum"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

You don't want the ad to be on top of your ScrollView, so you want to explicitly tell it to sit below the com.google.ads.AdView.